# How do I reliably determine folder size using FileSystemObject.Size?

Tags: windows, perl, win32ole, windows-scripting, filesystemobject

Trying to compute the size of a folder that could be very large, I used [`FileSystemObject.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d66skaf%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#! perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;

use File::Spec;
use Win32::OLE;

my $_fso;
sub folder_size {
  my($folder) = @_;

  $_fso = Win32::OLE->new("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    unless defined $_fso;

  die "GetFolder $folder: $^E"
    unless defined(my $f = $_fso->GetFolder($folder));

  my $size = $f->Size;
  die "Size $folder: $^E" unless defined $size;

  $size;
}
```

For some cases, `folder_size` returns normally, but for others, the call to `Size` throws exceptions. Computing the sizes of folders in `C:\` with

```
my $root = "C:/";
opendir my $dh, $root or die "$0: opendir: $!";

while (defined(my $name = readdir $dh)) {
  next if $name eq "." || $name eq "..";
  my $folder = File::Spec->catdir($root, $name);
  next unless -d $folder;

  chomp(my $size = eval { folder_size $folder } // $@);
  print "$folder - $size\n";
}
```

I get the following output:

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin - Size C:\$Recycle.Bin: The resource loader failed to find MUI file at olesize line 22.
C:\boot - 17463020
C:\cygwin - 1835711453
C:\DELL - 133184282
C:\doctemp - 12811140
C:\Documents and Settings - Size C:\Documents and Settings: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\Drivers - 180746384
C:\eclipse - 324690795
C:\EFI - 262144
C:\found.000 - Size C:\found.000: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\ghc - 1014658071
C:\gtk2hs - 138050118
C:\PerfLogs - Size C:\PerfLogs: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\Perl - 115648300
C:\Program Files - Size C:\Program Files: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\ProgramData - Size C:\ProgramData: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\Python25 - 83902423
C:\System Volume Information - Size C:\System Volume Information: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\Users - Size C:\Users: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\Virtual Machines - 5401825804
C:\Windows - Size C:\Windows: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\xampp - 408475320
```

It seems to be at least partially a permission issue because running the code as Administrator changes some of the output (noted in bold).

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin - 2062958143
C:\boot - 17463020
C:\cygwin - 1835711453
C:\DELL - 133184282
C:\doctemp - 12811140
C:\Documents and Settings - Size C:\Documents and Settings: The resource loader failed to find MUI file at olesize line 22.
C:\Drivers - 180746384
C:\eclipse - 324690795
C:\EFI - 262144
C:\found.000 - 8950
C:\ghc - 1014658071
C:\gtk2hs - 138050118
C:\PerfLogs - 0
C:\Perl - 115648300
C:\Program Files - 10857194364
C:\ProgramData - Size C:\ProgramData: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\Python25 - 83902423
C:\System Volume Information - Size C:\System Volume Information: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\Users - Size C:\Users: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\Virtual Machines - 5401825804
C:\Windows - Size C:\Windows: The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry at olesize line 22.
C:\xampp - 408475320
```

The MUI error message corresponds to [`ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_FOUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

How is my code incorrect?

For context, I have no requirement to use `FileSystemObject`. Other approaches I considered were scraping the output of `dir /s` and summing the sizes of all leaves in the subtree. For large directories, the output of `dir /s` could be enormous, and scouring an entire subtree is a performance dog. Windows Explorer always seems to be able to compute the result given enough time, so is there a way to call whatever it's doing?

Comment: I suspect Explorer is just ignoring the exceptions.  What happens if you try to measure one of the folders that's getting an exception using Explorer?

Comment: @cjm Explorer doesn't have any trouble with `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Windows`: the size in the property sheet settles down on an answer within 30 seconds. Plumbing the directories' depths with File::Find takes at least 5 times as long.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to stick to pure-perl: [Filesys::DiskUsage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys%3a%3aDiskUsage) does about the same thing.  However, I'm betting that permission issues will remain.  It should at least be better than scraping the output of `dir /s`.

To be honest, if Explorer works on these directories when you're not logged in as administrator, that seems like a privilege escalation issue in Explorer to me - apparently, Explorer can access the filesystem as if it were the administrator even when it isn't logged in as such, so if you can get your own DLL loaded by Explorer, you, too, could have admin access.